# Run N/Task on multiple saved searches at once

Tags: export, netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

Is there a straightforward way to modify the below code to execute on multiple saved searches and files simultaneously? I have all the file and search id's. but rather than creating 50 different scripts for each one can I just execute on a block of IDs by altering the below?

Thank you in advance.

All the Oracle documentation only seems to specify how to run these tasks on 1 item.

I know that a map/reduce script is a good path to go down for handling larger amounts of data, is that the way with this or can the below just be tweaked slightly?

```
/**

* @NApiVersion 2.x

* @NScriptType ScheduledScript

* @NModuleScope SameAccount

*/

define(['N/task'],

/**

* @param {record} record

* @param {search} search

*/

function(task) {

var FILE_ID = 433961; 

var SEARCH_ID = 1610;

function execute(scriptContext) {

var searchTask = task.create({

taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH

});

searchTask.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;

searchTask.fileId = FILE_ID;

var searchTaskId = searchTask.submit();

}

return {

execute: execute

};

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
/**    
  * @NApiVersion 2.x
  * @NScriptType ScheduledScript    
  * @NModuleScope SameAccount  
*/

define(['N/task'], function (task) {

  const todos = [
    {
      FILE_ID: 433961,
      SEARCH_ID: 1610
    },
    {
      FILE_ID: '...',
      SEARCH_ID: '...'
    },
    // ...
  ]

  function execute(scriptContext) {

    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
      var searchTask = task.create({
        taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
      });
  
      searchTask.savedSearchId = todo.SEARCH_ID;
      searchTask.fileId = todo.FILE_ID;
      var searchTaskId = searchTask.submit();
    })

  }

  return {
    execute: execute
  };

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. Have a good weekend.